# Can't fingure out what this is called

Tags: xcode4

Since I can't post a picture I am going to have to reference you to an app that does this. If you have the twitter app and you are going to retweet a tweet and that view comes up at the bottom, what is this called? And how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the Twitter app on iOS or Mac? And if on iOS, is it the iPhone or iPad version? (Make sure to tag your questions appropriately.)

Answer (score 0):

it's called a popup window. And the view it doesn't come @ the bottom but comes right below the tweet you opt to re tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Apple user interface model is that dialogs that slide up should be modal dialogs.

See: `presentModalViewController:animated` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Comment: Be aware that `presentModalViewController:animated:` is marked as deprecated in the [UIViewController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and that `presentViewController:animated:completion:` should be used in its place.